# ZF +  the reals are the countable union of countable sets consistent

Tags: set-theory

Hi, i know that it is consistent with ZF without choice that the reals are the countable union of countable sets.
Is there any good reference to read a proof?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that you say "the countable union of countable sets" instead of just "countable"?

Comment: Aaroni Tikuisis:  "Is there a reason to say `the countable union of countable sets' instead of just 'countable'?".   Yes.  The reals are not countable.

Comment: To elaborate: the result "countable union of countable sets is countable" requires some amount of the axiom of choice, which is not provable in ZF.

Comment: By contrast, ZF _does_ prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable.

Answer (score 13):

T. Jech, **The Axiom of Choice**. This particular proof appears in Chapter 10.

Essentially, the forcing goes through collapsing all the $\aleph_n$ (for finite $n$) to be countable, so in the full generic extension $\aleph_\omega$ of the ground model is countable too, but if we take permutations based on conditions based on finitely many collapses, then $\aleph_\omega$ of the ground model is not collapsed, and thus it becomes $\aleph_1$.

It is not difficult to show that if the ground model satisfied GCH then every real number in this symmetric extension came from a collapse of some $\aleph_n$, and those are countable. So we have that the real numbers are a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: If you are more comfortable with partial orders than with Boolean algebras, you may want to read the presentation of this result in Ioanna Dimitriou's master thesis, available at http://www.illc.uva.nl/Research/Reports/MoL-2006-03.text.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There are many references in Andres Caicedo's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/ In particular he refers to Jech's book "The axiom of choice" for a proof of this result.

Comment: It's theorem 10.6 in Jech's book, pp. 142

Comment: Paul, you asked for references. Jech's book is very good. If you want references other than this you should say that. 