# Does ZF bound countable unions of countable sets?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

ZF proves that whenever a countable union of countable sets can be well ordered then its cardinality is at most $\aleph_1$.  But what if it cannot be well ordered?  The Feferman-Levy model shows the continuum can be a countable union of countable sets.   Is there a ZF proof that a countable union of countable sets must be smaller than or equal to that in size?

Comment: I think that should be $\aleph_0$ in the first sentence.

Comment: Michael, no. It should be $\aleph_1$. If $\aleph_1$ is singular then it is the countable union of countable ordinals; but $\aleph_2$ (even if singular) can never be the countable union of *countable* ordinals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Jech *The Axiom of Choice*, problem 14 on chapter 5 states:

> Let $M$ be a transitive model of ZFC, there exists $M\subseteq N$ with the same cardinals as $M$ [read: initial ordinals] and the following statement is true in $N$:
>
> For every $\alpha$ there exists a set $X$ such that $X$ is a countable union of countable sets, and $\mathcal P(X)$ can be partitioned into $\aleph_\alpha$ nonempty sets.

Note that $\mathcal P(X)$ can only be mapped onto set many ordinals, so this ensures us that there is indeed a proper class of cardinalities which can be written as countable unions of countable sets.

Jech adds and points out that this $N$ is not an inner model of any transitive model of ZFC, as that would imply $2^{\aleph_0}$ can be partitioned into any number of sets. The reference given is to Morris from 1970:

> D. B. Morris, **A model of ZF which cannot be extended to a model of ZFC without adding ordinals**, *Notices Am. Math. Soc.* **17**, 577.

---

I haven't sat down to verify all the details, but it should probably work:

Using an Easton symmetry-like class forcing, we may obtain model add for every regular $\kappa$ a countable collection of countable subsets of $2^\kappa$ whose union is not countable, let us denote this union $A_\kappa$. Genericity arguments *should* give us that for $\kappa\neq\kappa'$, $|A_\kappa|$ is incomparable with $|A_{\kappa'}|$ - namely there are no injections between those two sets.

This shows that there is a proper class of different sets which can be represented as countable unions of countable sets. So no upper-bound is possible.

Comment: I am working on something similar in nature, so I will have the answer whether or not this argument is correct some time in the future. I will post an update when I'm done.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33028/can-iterating-countable-unions-give-every-set-zf/33032#33032 $\:$

Comment: Ricky, and? Smaller cardinality need not be countable. 

Comment: Oh yeah, I misread the question. $\:$

Comment: Just for anyone interested in this, I just posted on arXiv a proof of Morris' theorem: https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.10977